# Using Spry inside Java Server Faces framework

Tags: java, jsf, dreamweaver

I'm trying to insert a [Spry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spry_framework) [accordion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)) into an already existing [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) page using [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver). Is this possible?

I've already tried several things, and only the labels show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Dreamweaver expert, but all Spry Accordian requires is the correct HTML structure. E.g.:

```
   <div id="Accordion1" class="Accordion">
            <div class="AccordionPanel">
                <div class="AccordionPanelTab">Panel 1</div>
                <div class="AccordionPanelContent">
                    Panel 1 Content<br/>
                    Panel 1 Content<br/>
                    Panel 1 Content<br/>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Provided you have the [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) library loaded correctly, that should pretty much be all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing you might check is if your ids are getting munged by JSF.  Obviously that could impact the ability of Spry to wire itself to your accordion html structure.

+1 to Dave's answer.